# How to import and use a function from another dart file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I am making a app in which I am using package snake bottom navigation and advanced drawer. Both are configured fine in a file but I'm having issue when when I want to use the function on a new page to open and close the drawer. I am unable to import it to my HomePage file where I am making the home page of the app. This code

```
void _handleMenuButtonPressed() {
        _advancedDrawerController.showDrawer();
      }
```

is the one creating issue in the drawer screen onpressed and on valuelistener.
Here is my Dashboard code which contains bottom nav and drawer:

```
    class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final _advancedDrawerController = AdvancedDrawerController();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  ShapeBorder? bottomBarShape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
  );
  SnakeBarBehaviour snakeBarStyle = SnakeBarBehaviour.floating;
  EdgeInsets padding = const EdgeInsets.all(12);
  SnakeShape snakeShape = SnakeShape.circle;

  bool showSelectedLabels = true;
  bool showUnselectedLabels = true;

  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;
  Gradient selectedGradient =
      const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.amber]);

  Color unselectedColor = Colors.black;
  Gradient unselectedGradient =
      const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black]);

  Color? containerColor;
  List<Color> containerColors = [
    const Color(0xFFFDE1D7),
    const Color(0xFFE4EDF5),
    const Color(0xFFE7EEED),
    const Color(0xFFF4E4CE),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdvancedDrawer(
      backdropColor: kblue,
      controller: _advancedDrawerController,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      animateChildDecoration: true,
      rtlOpening: false,
      disabledGestures: false,
      childDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
      ),
      drawer: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: kblue,
          child: ListTileTheme(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            iconColor: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 128.0,
                  height: 128.0,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 24.0,
                    bottom: 64.0,
                  ),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/logo.png',
                    scale: 3,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Home',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Profile',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Notifications',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.bug_report),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Report a bug',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Logout',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 16.0,
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Terms of Service | Privacy Policy',
                        style: TextStyle(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        extendBody: true,
        bottomNavigationBar: SnakeNavigationBar.color(
          behaviour: snakeBarStyle,
          snakeShape: snakeShape,
          shape: bottomBarShape,
          padding: padding,
          snakeViewColor: selectedColor,
          selectedItemColor: snakeShape == SnakeShape.indicator
              ? selectedColor
              : Colors.orange,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          showUnselectedLabels: showUnselectedLabels,
          showSelectedLabels: showSelectedLabels,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'tickets'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'calendar'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'home'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'microphone'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'search'),
          ],
          selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
        ),
        body: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: const <Widget>[
            HomePage(),
            HomePage(),
            HomePage(),
            HomePage(),
            HomePage(),
          ],
          onPageChanged: (page) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = page;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _handleMenuButtonPressed() {
    _advancedDrawerController.showDrawer();
  }
}
```

Code to HomePage which contains the button to open and close the drawer and thats where the issue is:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
                      icon: ValueListenableBuilder<AdvancedDrawerValue>(
                        valueListenable: _advancedDrawerController,
                        builder: (_, value, __) {
                          return AnimatedSwitcher(
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                            child: Icon(
                              value.visible ? Icons.clear : Icons.menu,
                              key: ValueKey<bool>(value.visible),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the project file structure or the locations and names of the files you mentioned above so that we can provide an example.

Comment: I've mentioned the file names they don't require any previous file except of color one which can be ignored by anyone marking color is too basic so I dont know what else is required these 2 files are sufficient. From the dashboard class file code the homepage is connected the issue is coming from dashboard class file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way. There's no need to separate the files when you can do in one

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final _advancedDrawerController = AdvancedDrawerController();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  ShapeBorder? bottomBarShape = const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
  );

  SnakeBarBehaviour snakeBarStyle = SnakeBarBehaviour.floating;
  EdgeInsets padding = const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0);
  SnakeShape snakeShape = SnakeShape.circle;
  final double elevation = 4;
  bool showSelectedLabels = true;
  bool showUnselectedLabels = true;
  Color selectedColor = Colors.white;
  Gradient selectedGradient =
      const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.pink]);
  Color unselectedColor = Colors.black;
  Gradient unselectedGradient =
      const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black]);
  Color? containerColor;
  List<Color> containerColors = [
    const Color(0xFFFDE1D7),
    const Color(0xFFE4EDF5),
    const Color(0xFFE7EEED),
    const Color(0xFFF4E4CE),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdvancedDrawer(
      backdropColor: kblue,
      controller: _advancedDrawerController,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      animateChildDecoration: true,
      rtlOpening: false,
      disabledGestures: false,
      childDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
      ),
      drawer: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: kblue,
          child: ListTileTheme(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            iconColor: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 128.0,
                  height: 128.0,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 24.0,
                    bottom: 64.0,
                  ),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/logo.png',
                    scale: 3,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const Dashboard()));
                  },
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Home',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {},
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Profile',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const NotificationsScreen()));
                  },
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Notifications',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ReportBug()));
                  },
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.bug_report),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Report a bug',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const LoginPage()));
                  },
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                  title: const Text(
                    'Logout',
                    style: TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const TermsandPolicies()));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 16.0,
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Terms of Service | Privacy Policy',
                        style: TextStyle(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'Dhrop',
            style: TextStyle(
              letterSpacing: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
            icon: ValueListenableBuilder<AdvancedDrawerValue>(
              valueListenable: _advancedDrawerController,
              builder: (_, value, __) {
                return AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                  child: Icon(
                    value.visible ? Icons.clear : Icons.menu,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    key: ValueKey<bool>(value.visible),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        extendBody: true,
        bottomNavigationBar: SnakeNavigationBar.color(
          backgroundColor: kblue,
          behaviour: snakeBarStyle,
          snakeShape: snakeShape,
          shape: bottomBarShape,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: 15,
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
          ),
          snakeViewColor: selectedColor,
          selectedItemColor:
              snakeShape == SnakeShape.indicator ? selectedColor : kblue,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          showUnselectedLabels: showUnselectedLabels,
          showSelectedLabels: showSelectedLabels,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const HomePage()));
                },
              ),
              // label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const SearchPage()));
                },
              ),
              // label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.message,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const MessagesPage()));
                },
              ),
              // label: 'Messages',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.luggage,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const DropPage()));
                },
              ),
              // label: 'Drop',
            ),
          ],
          selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
        ),
        body: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          children: const <Widget>[
            HomePage(),
            SearchPage(),
            MessagesPage(),
            DropPage()
          ],
          onPageChanged: (page) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = page;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleMenuButtonPressed() {
    _advancedDrawerController.showDrawer();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked